# When is 終わる used as a transitive verb?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

On [Are 終わる and 済ませる synonyms?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/are-%E7%B5%82%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B-and-%E6%B8%88%E3%81%99%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B-synonyms), there were some questions whether `終わる` is used as a transitive verb.

Space ALC seems to have a few results for [`を終わる`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%82%92%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/UTF-8/), but far more for [`を終わらせる`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%89%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B) and [`を終える`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%92%E7%B5%82%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B). Looking at sense 4 of the [Daijisen definition](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02656200), it does seem `終わる` can be used as a transitive verb:

> しまいにする。終える。「会議を―・ります」

**My question:** How often is `終わる` used as a transitive verb and when is it used in such a way compared to `終わらせる` and `終える`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

終わる is used both as a transitive verb and an intransitive verb, whereas 終える is used only as a transitive verb.  When 終わる is used as a transitive verb, it is almost synonymous to 終える.  The only exception I can think of is that a closing word of a speech or other verbal communication is usually …を終わります instead of …を終えます.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at [this dictionary reference](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E7%B5%82%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0), it seems like the times where 終わる　might be used like a transitive verb would be when one is *putting an end to* something.

For example:

> これで私のスピーチを終わります。

Or another example (according to "bridge road hight"さん in [this answer](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1213636922),) :

> 「授業を終わる」→先生（講師）側
>   「授業を終える」→生徒（受講者）側

Basically, a teacher might say something like *"I finished (teaching) the class."*  whereas a student would say something like *"I finished (taking) the class."*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, that link says that `を終わります` is used by the organizers/hosts to conclude some event etc. That makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I think that from students’ viewpoint, it is 授業が終わる, neither 授業を終える nor 授業を終わる.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto That does sound more natural, at least.

Comment: So... what's the difference between "ending sth" and "putting an end to sth"?

Comment: https://c.tenor.com/Ik6Su144SNsAAAAd/bola-de-feno-desert.gif