# How do you say "stopped playing piano" by using やめる?

Tags: verbs

Is it

> ピアノを弾いてやめました。

or

> ピアノを弾きやめました。

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither is correct. Unlike 始める or 終える which can follow almost any verb, やめる can *not* follow the masu-stem of an arbitrary verb. (There are a few fixed compound verbs like [取りやめる](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8A%E6%AD%A2%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B), though)

You have to use a nominalizer and say:

> ピアノを弾くのをやめました。

Compare:

> - ピアノを弾き始めました。 I started playing the piano.
> - ピアノを弾き終えました。 I finished playing the piano.

Comment: Is the difference between "I stopped playing piano [now]" and "I stopped playing piano [altogether]" best translated as 「ピアノを弾き終えました」 and 「ピアノを弾くのをやめました」? Can you say 「ピアノをやめました」 for the latter?

Comment: hmm, I thought you could add やむ to stem verbs, like in 泣きやむ. Is this different because it is intransitive? Only possible with やむ and not やめる？

Comment: @Earthliŋ ピアノをやめました only means "I quit the habit of playing the piano" or "I ended my career as a pianist." ピアノを弾き終えました means finishing one particular performance. ピアノを弾くのをやめました can mean both depending on the context.

Comment: @kandyman I recommend you first visit [this site](http://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/en/) and learn about syntactic compound verbs. 始める can directly follow any verb, やむ can follow some verbs, やめる can follow only very few verbs. Also please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52803/5010). You can say 泣き止む and 降り止む, but not 食べ止む nor 歩き止む.