# 仕事が終わる or 仕事を終える

Tags: grammar, transitivity

What are the differences in nuance between the following sentences?

A:父は仕事が終わり次第、毎日まっすぐ帰宅します。

B:父は仕事を終え次第、毎日まっすぐ帰宅します。

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/45334/9831 / (... and maybe https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5043/9831 , too?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both common, and there is no practical difference. I think even a person who can freely decide when to leave his office doesn't make a clear distinction between them.