# What is the difference between 合わす and 合わせる?

Tags: verbs, conjugations, causation

I am a little confused, is this just a transitive intransitive pair? I could not find an answer so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43474/causative-%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%95%e3%81%9b%e3%82%8b-vs-%e3%81%99-%e3%81%95%e3%81%99/43479#43479

Comment: Duplicate? -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5161/9831　or 
 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43474/9831

Comment: OK. I don't think my question is a duplicate, but I gather both words are different versions of the 使役形. Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: It's almost same.

Answer (score 0):

They're both transitive verbs, and they're pretty much the same thing. You can use them interchangeably.